# Type inheritance checks in Dart based solely on Type instances

Tags: flutter, dart

Given two `Type` instances in Dart (Flutter), is there a way to determine whether one type inherits or implements the other?

```dart
final Type first = aTypeFromSomewhere;
final Type second = aTypeFromSomewhereElse;

// How can I determine if first inherits from second?
```

[The `Type` class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Type-class.html) doesn't seem to have any functionality around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with dart:mirrors:

```
import 'dart:mirrors';

class A {}

class B extends A {}

void main() {
  final typeA = A().runtimeType;
  final typeB = B().runtimeType;

  final classMirrorA = reflectClass(typeA);
  final classMirrorB = reflectClass(typeB);

  print(classMirrorA.isSubclassOf(classMirrorB)); // false
  print(classMirrorB.isSubclassOf(classMirrorA)); // true
}
```

A lot more complicated way to do the same (but are supported by flutter) are to use the [reflectable](https://pub.dev/packages/reflectable) package. The package has a lot of limitations and are not really that great to work with. But it can build the needed reflections in a build phase.

I have made the following example which does the same as my previous but now without using dart:mirrors:

```
import 'package:reflectable/reflectable.dart';
import 'main.reflectable.dart';

@MyReflectable()
class A {}

@MyReflectable()
class B extends A {}

class MyReflectable extends Reflectable {
  const MyReflectable()
      : super(typeRelationsCapability, superclassQuantifyCapability);
}

const myReflectable = const MyReflectable();

void main() {
  initializeReflectable();

  final typeA = A().runtimeType;
  final typeB = B().runtimeType;

  final classMirrorA = myReflectable.reflectType(typeA);
  final classMirrorB = myReflectable.reflectType(typeB);

  print(classMirrorA.isSubtypeOf(classMirrorB)); // false
  print(classMirrorB.isSubtypeOf(classMirrorA)); // true
}
```

To use this you need to add the following dependencies to your pubspec.yaml:

```
reflectable: ^2.1.0
build_runner: ^1.6.0
build_runner_core: ^3.0.0
```

And run the following command (if your reflected classes are in bin):

Not that all classes your want to have use isSubtypeOf on needs to have itself and all superclasses specified with "@MyReflectable()" so the precompiler can detect it.

```
pub run build_runner build bin/
```

Comment: I was afraid of that, because I'm using Flutter which doesn't support mirrors. Kinda hoped something so fundamental wouldn't require Mirrors. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, if you want a working solution for Flutter you should really specify it in the question (which you have now). I have something working for you and I am updating my answer. :)

Comment: Thanks. Whilst I can't actually use this, it's obviously the best available recourse.